# PHP nl2br for text content but make it exclude on javascript content

Tags: javascript, php, nl2br

I need to use nl2br function on page content coming from DB. But `<br />` tag added to into javascript content too.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><br />
let test = "test";<br />
let menu = "menu";<br />
</script>
```

Firstly for make add br to all content and than remove br from javascript content, I did try this:

```
<?php
//content coming from db
$content = nl2br($content);
$content = preg_replace("/<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script\b[^>]*>/m", str_replace("<br />", "", nl2br($content)), $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Result: br not added into javascript but javascript and text content did come twice (br didn't worked on first text content but worked on second text content)

How can I exclude br in javascript code?

Comment: I know it is somewhat superfluous to say this: But you start with a bad design, putting whole pages in your database, but it can happen. Then, for some untold reason you need to add `<br />` into that page. Which is just weird. And to top all this off, you have to compensate by removing the `<br />` from Javascript. One bad decision piled on top of another. Could you please answer the question why you want to put these `<br />` into, what must be, perfect HTML?

Comment: You application may be wide open to XSS

Comment: @medilies: That may be true, but it would be helpful to readers if you explained why you think this is the case.

Comment: Web page builders putting whole pages in their database with html blocks. This contents sending to database only by admins. Ofcourse there will extra security (xss and etc) in code for admins and also on page too for showing contents. Actually it is possible to newline with `<p>` tag but some web site admins wants to make this with easy way with `\n` (they are clicking to enter button after text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your regex suites your need, you can use `preg_replace_callback` to achieve what you want.

```
//content coming from db
$content = preg_replace_callback("/<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script\b[^>]*>/m",function($matches){return str_replace('<br />','',$matches[0]);},nl2br($content));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Worked perfectly. I will practice on this `preg_replace_callback` function.